# Upvoting vs accepting answers

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, up-votes

This is not so much a question but more an observation on a distinction between upvoting and accepting an answer.

It seems to me that upvoting is in a way rewarded more: even though it gives 10 rep (accepting 5 more), it can be done many times for one answer. Also, upvoting counts towards some badges. Yet SO is about questions and answers and I guess questions with an accepted answer are generally treated as closed and not worth spending time on providing more answers.

Also, some users (especially beginners) seem to be a bit randomly either upvote or mark the answer.

Should it be made more clear to the person asking a question what those options mean?

Comment: 3 people downvoted this question. Yes, it's not the best question in the world, for sure. But isn't meta a place for discussion? Sometimes it really feels like Facebook with a dislike button added.

Comment: You are aware that on Meta, votes are also used to express agreement/disagreement?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't. Great, another thing learnt today :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upvote means "it's useful", acceptance means "It worked for me". Often answers that are useful does not work, for example by solving only one part of a problem. And sometimes answer that works is not really useful, it just allows to get things going "by the rote", leaving OP with no clue what and why is really happening. And it is described on the tooltips and in [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), what do you want more? For me it's good enough already, if someone have any doubts after reading, he can ask on meta. If someone refuses to read, changing descriptions will not change a thing.

[image]

Comment: Right when i was explaining this i've seen your ever faster answer! lol

Comment: @BerkerYüceer sorry ;)

Comment: I don't think it's clear enough to beginners especially. I remember when I started, it was rather confusing. And I didn't know meta existed.

Comment: @Szymon In help center *What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?* is the first article on the *Answering* list. And it's explained in intro, under *Anybody can answer*. It's impossible to put it in more visible places. If someone skips intro and help center, we can't force-help him.

Comment: I guess you're right. But then, most people don't bother reading help, they just click around. Oh well, what can you do...